# Is it possible for a MS Teams bot to insert a card into the user's current conversation?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Ideally what I would like to do is for a MS Teams user to perform an action in my app running on the same machine that would result in  a card being inserted into the user's current message.

I suspect that that is not possible, so the next best thing would be if my app sends the data to a server where a message action in MS Teams could then fetch it and insert it into the current message.

Is it possible for a message action to insert a card into the current message without posting a modal popup?

I know I could use "pro-active" messaging but that will always add the card to a new conversation which looses the context for it.

Comment: the question's a little unclear - are you asking if it's possible to post a new message to an existing "thread", rather than to start a new thread each time?

Comment: do you want to send message in existing conversation reference? A bot confusing are you talking about Bot or message extension?\

Comment: Sorry, when I said 'conversation' I actually meant message.  I have updated the question.

Comment: You can use [CcontinueConversationAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.botframeworkadapter.continueconversationasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) for the same